# Сдвиг части текста С++

Tags: c++, строки

Как можно сдвинуть часть текста? Например, из слова "привет" сделать "при вет". Без `memmove`.

Comment: Все равно придется заново выделять память, потому что размер стал больше, а потом копировать, что равносильно memmove

Comment: Если память в хвосте есть, то копировать, начиная с `'\0'` после `'т'`, двигаясь к началу. По сути тот же *memmove*

Answer (score 1):

Идиоматичный код это

```
std::string s = "привет";
s.insert(3, " ");
```